# Unexpected behaviour of Merge Sort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have tested the merge method and it is working fine for all the cases but somehow the mergeSort method is not producing the correct output, it simply divides the array into smaller sub arrays and then it is passed to the method which merges them.

```
public class MergeSort {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{

         int a[]={2,4,5,7,1,2,3,6};

         System.out.println("Unsorted Array");
         for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
         }

         int p=0,r=7;
         try{
            MergeSort m=new MergeSort();



            m.mergeSort(a,0,7);
         }
         catch(Exception e )
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         System.out.println("\nSorted Array");
         for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
         }
      }

      void mergeSort(int a[],int p,int r)
      {
          int q;
          if(p<r)
          {
              q= (p+r)/2;
              System.out.print("  "+q);
              mergeSort(a,p,q);
              mergeSort(a,q+1,r);
              merge(a,p,q,r);
          }


      }

      int [] merge(int a[],int p,int q,int r){
      //int a[]={2,4,5,7,1,2,3,6};
      int n1=q-p+2;
      int n2=r-q+1;

      int L[]=new int[n1];
      int R[]=new int[n2];

      for(int i=0;i<n1 -1;i++){
        L[i]=a[i];
      }
      L[n1 -1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      //q=q+1;
      for(int i=0;i<n2 -1;i++){
        R[i]=a[q+i+1];

      }
      R[n2-1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      //L[n1+1]=9;
      ///R[n2+1]=9;

      int i=0,j=0;

      for(int k = p; k <= r; k++){
          if(L[i] <= R[j]){
            a[k] = L[i++];
        }else{
            a[k] = R[j++];
        }
      }
      return a;
     }
    }
```

Comment: It would help of you had better variable names to read your code. Just putting letters makes it hard to determine the variables usage.

Comment: In particular, having two variable `r` and `R` in the same method tends to confuse (no matter than one is a parameter). Java varaibles (and parameters) conventionally begin with a small letter.

Comment: Just a note that your midpoint is broken `q = (p+r)/2`. What happens when `p` and `r` are large enough that the result overflows to a negative number, then you divide the negative number by 2? That index will be invalid. The fix looks like `q = (p+r) >>> 1`. Now the overflow can happen and the bits are then shifted back into place giving the correct positive index that was expected.

Comment: @Imposter, that would require an array larger than 1 000 000 000 entries, taking up 4 Gb of RAM. For an exercise like this maybe we can leave that out of consideration. Otherwise you are quite right, of course. I think I’d prefer `(int) (((long) p + (long) q) / 2);`. It’s longer, but clearer to the average programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I’m sorry, your merge method is not working correctly in all cases. At a point during your sorting you are calling `merge()` with arguments `[2, 2, 4, 7, 1, 2, 3, 6]`, `4`, `4` and `5`. This ought to leave the array unchanged, but it changes the array to `[2, 2, 4, 7, 2, 2, 3, 6]` — there is a 2 where there was a 1.

I believe the bug is in these lines in `merge()`:

```
  for(int i=0;i<n1 -1;i++){
    L[i]=a[i];
  }
```

You ought to be taking the elements from `a` starting at index `p`. Instead you are starting from index 0. In the first few calls to `merge()`, `p` is 0, so it makes no difference, so I understand how you could miss the bug in your tests. Later when `p` is 2 or 4, things start to go wrong.

Comment: So the loop should be `for(int i=0, j=p; i<n1 - 1; i++,j++){ L[i] = a[j] };`

Comment: That’s one option. Another option goes more like the loop for filling `R` in the following lines. I trust the OP to pick the solution she or he prefers.